# upload multiple image through Http Url Connection to server in Android

Tags: android, image, httpurlconnection, image-uploading

i have to upload multiple images to a server but not in queue ...i mean i have to add two different images separately (need to send two images in such a way that it populates two different columns in the `db`) by using `httpurlconnection`:

```
private void uploadFile(String selectedFilePath) {

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("loading");
    pd.show();

    Log.d("enter", "Entering" + selectedFilePath);

    if (selectedFilePath.equals("null")) {
        selectedFilePath = "";
    }

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);

    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
        // dialog.dismiss();

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });

    } else {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("image", fileName);
            connection.setRequestProperty("proof_file", fileName);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            String aID = "10";
            Log.e("Sending", "Sending userID");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"a_id\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(aID);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


            String saID = "1";
            Log.e("Sending", "Sending SocietyID");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"s_id\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(saID);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(name);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("38398393");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);



            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"address\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("abc");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"h_type\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("ty");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            //..............................
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"proof_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);



            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(String.valueOf(destination));
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            //...................9/6..................
            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            // Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            Log.d("wer", serverResponseMessage);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
              MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully uploaded to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use following Simple Utility https://paste.ubuntu.com/24907606/ for uploading multiple file , `addFilePart` this method is used to add fille